# How can I merge meeting chat threads in MS Teams, and ensure that future meeting invitations are attached to the same chat?

Tags: chat, microsoft-teams

In MS Teams I have some repeating meetings that have been scheduled perpetually and so have all of the meeting chat in a single thread. That's perfect, since the chat is one long thread going back and covering all of the meeting instances.

I have other meetings, though, where the meeting chat is split into multiple threads. Sometimes the initial meetings may have been scheduled for six months and then a new meeting with the same name was scheduled for another six months, or a repeating meeting had changes made to the meeting dates. In either case we end up with multiple meeting chats with the same name.

The chats are all ad-hoc/private created as a result of scheduling a Teams meeting; none are related to a specific Team or Channel.

It's inefficient, along with being frustrating and confusing for users, to have three different "Manager Meeting" instances with the chat contents spread between them. I have two questions, then:

1. How can I fix where I'm at now, by merging the multiple meeting chats into a single thread?
2. For future meetings, how can I schedule them so that they're attached to the existing chat thread, rather than starting a new one?

I don't see anything in the menus related to merging chat threads, and as I've searched I've found instructions about merging channels, or merging two meetings when both are occurring at the same time, but nothing about how to merge more than one meeting chat.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not feasible to merge more than one meeting chat.

If you wish you can suggest this feature here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)